# How do I use & access a Backbone.js Collection as property/attribute in a Model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-associations, backbone-relational, backbone.js-collections

I'm new to Backbone (still stuck in Ruby on Rails mode) and am a bit confused about how to add a Collection to a Model as a property/attribute (is "attribute" the correct term?).

For example, I have a Model named `current_plan`, and a variable named `json_dump` that was returned from the server that includes an array of `participants`. I want it to have an attribute named `participants` (which is a Collection of participants), fill it from the json_dump.participants variable, and be able to use code like `current_plan.participants.where({first_name: "Dan"}).

Here are some snippets of my initialize function:

```
var current_plan = new Plan();

current_plan.set({attribute: val} ...other attributes... );
current_plan.participants = new Backbone.Collection(json_dump.participants);
```

But that forces me to access regular attributes like: `current_plan.attributes.attribute`. Also, I can see that there is correct data in the `current_plan.attributes.participants.models`, but I can't figure out how to use any of the Collection methods on `current_plan`.

Clearly I don't understand what's going on, and why there are so many extra layers involved. The Backbone docs seem a little sparse, and I haven't been able to find anything on SO or Google searches that match what I want to do. If there's another question or tutorial out there that explains this, I'd greatly appreciate someone pointing me that way. I also saw the [Backbone Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) project which seems like it may be what I need, but I'd prefer not to add more complication to Backbone until I understand the basics.

Thanks for any help you can provide to help a new Backbone user out!

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because i haven't tried it out but backbone has bit me many times when I forget that the model wants me to use "get" instead of accessing properties directly like so:

current_plan.get('participants')  any chance that helps?

Comment: Jason, I tried that, but it just returns the Collection and doesn't allow me to use any of the Collection methods on it. Thanks though :)

Comment: current_plan.participants = ... doesn't seem like it should work to me, I would think you would want current_plan.set({participants: ...});   also, did you check if the Backbone collection is working correctly before you assign it to the model?

Comment: It got answered, but not by the answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the backbone framework doesn't have a official way to handle relationships between models and collections i think, and i don't use backbone relational, but i have multiple relationships in my backbone collections/models.
when i am defining a relationship model with a collection i use it as a property of the model object, not a backbone atribute, so:

```
var current_plan = new Backbone.Model(); //or backbone model extended 
current_plan.participants = new Backbone.Collection(json_dump.participants);
```

then as @andrew-hubbs says you should always use the backbone api to deal with models and collections attributes to have consistency in your code along with backbone versions for example.
then you can access/set the model properties like this

```
current_plan.get('property'); 
participant = current_plan.participants.get(1);
participant.get('property');
participant.set('name', 'bob');
```

Comment: I usually go with this approach, preferring to keep my attributes flat and easily serializable.  It's personal preference to some degree though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentPlan = new Plan(); // Assuming Plan is a Backbone.Model
currentPlan.set("participants", new Backbone.Collection(json_dump.participants));
currentPlan.get("participants") instanceof Backbone.Collection
currentPlan.get("participants").at(0) instanceof Backbone.Model
```

You should always access the attributes hash on Backbone models through the `get`/`set` methods. If this is not working then your `json_dump.participants` is probably not formated correctly. You can see an example from the documentation of this kind of [collection instantiation here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON).

Yes Backbone.Relational is a project to handle basically exactly this. It allows you to define relationships between models. It then makes it very easy to automatically create the collections as attributes on instances of the models.